# qnx momentics build errors

Tags: blackberry, qnx

I had a problem building blackberry cascade projects. The project has no problem in building  for simulator debug, but for device-release and device-debug, the build always fails. I don't know why it is like this. Any Solutions?

```
make[2]: [o.le-v7-g/.obj/YoudaoDict.gch/c++] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Yu Han/Desktop/YoudaoDict/arm'
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Yu Han/Desktop/YoudaoDict/arm'
make[1]: [debug] Error 2
make:[Device-Debug] Error 2
```